# How to check req.body empty or not in node ,express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Below is my request body and which is sending from client side

```
var  credentials = {

"ConsumerData": {

            "ConsumerStoreId": "a",
            "ConsumerUserId": "a"
        },
        "CustomerData": {

            "CustomerId": "2345678890"
        },
        "ErnD": {
            "UID": "3",
            "TxnDt": "1"
        },

        "PurD": [{
                "ItemCode": "3456tghw3",
                "ItemEANCode": "223222122"

            },
            {
                "ItemCode": "8jghw3865",
                "ItemEANCode": "3334443222"

            }
        ]
}
```

for testing i am sending `var  credentials = {}` empty credentials

In server side controller(node,express) i want to check req.body empty or not

```
if(!req.body)

{
 console.log('Object missing');
}
if(!req.body.ConsumerData.ConsumerStoreId)
  {
  console.log('ConsumerStoreId missing');
  }
 if(!req.body.CustomerData.CustomerId)
  {
  console.log('CustomerId missing');
  }
  if(!req.body.ErnD.UID)
  {
  console.log('UID missing');
  }
    console.log('outside');
```

i am checking everything but alwasys its printing outside only

Answer (score 20):

**ES2015:**

```
if(req.body.constructor === Object && Object.keys(req.body).length === 0) {
  console.log('Object missing');
}
```

**PRE ES2015:**

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    for(var prop in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            return false;
    }
    return JSON.stringify(obj) === JSON.stringify({});
}

if(isEmpty(req.body)) {
    console.log('Object missing');
}
```

For more ways in a **pre es2015** style: https://coderwall.com/p/_g3x9q/how-to-check-if-javascript-object-is-empty

Comment: if(!req.body.ConsumerData.ConsumerStoreId)
  {
  console.log('ConsumerStoreId missing');
  }

Comment: @itsme Can you explain please?

Comment: above code is working but for this what i need to do if(!req.body.ConsumerData.ConsumerStoreId)
  {
  console.log('ConsumerStoreId missing');
  }

Comment: @itsme Do you want me to change to this?

Comment: i done something its not working thtas why can you please help me out so that it will help me to move forward

Comment: What do you get when you ```console.log(req.body)```?

Comment: {"ConsumerData": {

            "ConsumerStoreId": "a",
            "ConsumerUserId": "a"
        },
        "CustomerData": {

            "CustomerId": ""
        },
        "ErnD": {
            "UID": "3",
            "TxnDt": "1"
        },

        "PurD": [{
                "ItemCode": "3456tghw3",
                "ItemEANCode": "223222122"

            },
            {
                "ItemCode": "8jghw3865",
                "ItemEANCode": "3334443222"

            }
        ]
}

Comment: It's works perfectly. It's not printing 'Object missing'.

Comment: its working fine only but CustomerId i am getting empty how to handle this

Comment: @itsme Got you. just add else before the next ```if```s.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138612/discussion-between-its-me-and-yuval-pruss).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867811/how-to-do-user-already-there-update-if-not-there-create-in-particular-collecti

Answer (score 13):

```
if (Object.keys(req.body).length === 0) {
   // Do something
}
```

Comment: Can you actually console.log(typeof req.body) and make sure its not returning undefined?

Comment: let data = {"ConsumerData": { "ConsumerStoreId": "a", "ConsumerUserId": "a" }, "CustomerData": { "CustomerId": "" }, "ErnD": { "UID": "3", "TxnDt": "1" }, "PurD": [{ "ItemCode": "3456tghw3", "ItemEANCode": "223222122" }, { "ItemCode": "8jghw3865", "ItemEANCode": "3334443222" } ] }

console.log(Object.keys(data).length===0) // false

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Comment: short and sweet....

Answer (score 3):

When the req.body is empty, it returns an empty object, as such, making `!req.body` return `false` even when it's empty. Instead, you should test for `!Object.keys(req.body).length`. What it will do is take every key from the object and count, if no keys where found it would return `0`. Then all we need to do is use the same method that we use on empty arrays, testing for !arr.length making it possible to receive a boolean stating it's fullness or the lack of it.

Then, we end up with the code:

```
router.post('/auth/signup', function(req, res) {
    if(!Object.keys(req.body).length) {
        // is empty
    } else if(!req.body.param1 || !req.body.param2 || !req.body.param3) {
        let params = [req.body.param1, req.body.param2, req.body.param3];
        let lackingParam = params.findIndex(param => !param === true) > 0 ? params.findIndex(param => !param === true) > 1 ? "req.body.param3" : "req.body.param2" : "req.body.param1";
        // lacking only lackingParam
    } else {
        // not empty
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using [lodash.isempty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.isempty)?

```
const isEmpty = require('lodash.isempty');

if(isEmpty(req.body)) {
    console.log('Empty Object');
}
```

Here are the docs https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isEmpty

> Checks if value is an empty object, collection, map, or set.
>
> Objects are considered empty if they have no own enumerable string
> keyed properties.
>
> Array-like values such as arguments objects, arrays, buffers, strings,
> or jQuery-like collections are considered empty if they have a length
> of 0. Similarly, maps and sets are considered empty if they have a
> size of 0.