# Node.js catch empty POST request body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, body-parser

I am trying to catch a POST request with an empty body before it causes my server to crash. I've seen people using bodyparser but I am using the MVC model and basically I don't have references to app in this .js file.

```
var resource = req.body;
if(!resource) return res.status(400).send("Your request is missing details.");
```

I was told to try something like this but it still does not work. When I console.log resource it appears as "{}" even when no body was added in postman, so the null check doesn't work. If anyone has any advice I would appreciate it!

Comment: `console.log(resource)` should return `{}` when the body is empty. But the test should still pass. That is, `!resource` will be `false`. What response do you get from postman?

Comment: Yes that is what is happening. Do you know of a better way to check if the body is empty? In postman I get a 200 but it continues on to crash my server later with a "response headers can't be changed after they are set". I think the reason is that an API I'm using throws an error but I've already sent the status code 200.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42921727/how-to-check-req-body-empty-or-not-in-node-express/42921907

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:
`if(Object.keys(req.body).length === 0)`

or  `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(req.body).length == 0`

And then your logic to respond to the user.